# What is the use of \a in C?

Tags: c, escaping, warnings, alert

I stumbled upon the `\a` escape sequence in a piece of text in ISO/IEC 9899:2018 (C18), Section 5.2.2/2 - "Character display semantics":

> \a (alert) Produces an audible or visible alert without changing the active position.

I´ve never seen this used in any C code to indicate an error. By the way, I didn´t know that an escape sequence *can/could* trigger an audible signal on some systems.

- What is/was the certain use of that `\a` escape sequence?
- Is it a remain from the earlier days of C, that is obsolete now?
- And in which situation it would be or were (if it is obsolete today) appreciated to use that? Can you provide an example?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Reference: [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_character)

Comment: Who told you it was used instead of other error messages?

Comment: @machine_1 Noone, It was just an assumption of mine by asking for it; I apologize and edited the question. But questions are made to get answers. If I´d know that it is not in any case a substitution, I hadn´t ask for it and in fact, I didn´t got a clear answer to that until now.

Comment: BTW: BEL is not an escape sequence. The backslash notation is only used to represent it in strings. `\007` or `\x07` would also do (assuming ASCII character coding)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - What is/was the certain use of that \a escape sequence?

According to the same section of the standard you were reading,

> Alphabetic escape sequences representing nongraphic characters in the execution character set are intended to produce actions on display devices as follows

The particular action that a `\a` sequence is intended to produce is what you quoted.  This is in fact used rarely, if ever, in modern code, and typical C implementations just map that sequence to a single ASCII character that has the same significance, relying on the terminal driver to handle the actual alert.  You're more likely to see the effect if you accidentally output a binary file to a terminal than just about any other way.

> - Is it a remain from the earlier days of C, that is obsolete now?

I am not aware of it being used for the purpose described in any code I have ever seen.  In that sense, yes, it is obsolete, but from the perspective of the standard, that provision is *not* obsolete.

> - And in which situation it would be or were (if it is obsolete today) appreciated to use that? Can you provide an example?

You would include that sequence in a string that is printed to `stdout`.  When the string is printed, you (maybe) get a bell sound and / or the screen flashes and / or something similar.

```
printf("Ring the bell...\a\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

- `\a` Isn't always used for an error
- It is an ascii character and can be used anywhere.
- `\a` Is used to display a sound. You can try by typing `printf '\a'` in bash.